# Error when using shared preferences to login in kotlin

Tags: android, authentication, kotlin, sharedpreferences

Im trying to use shared preference in order to skip the login activity. If the user click in the checkbox it means that the next time he uses de app he will go directly to de main activity.[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfj43.png)

```
val checkbox = checkBoxLog

    val sharedPref:SharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("prefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()

    if(checkbox.isChecked){
        editor.putBoolean("Checkbox", true)
        editor.apply()
        Log.d("hola", "presente")
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
```

Comment: Are you using fragments? or all activities?

Comment: I separated the app by modules where an activity is attached to some fragments

Comment: Copy and paste your code here!

Comment: what error are you having, this post is too scarce

Comment: also, you are checking a property from the checkbox then saving that in the shared preference and never linked those two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show a example flow how you can skip the login fragment when once the user is registered or get's past from login fragment without skipping completely.

When user launches app first time and login fragment shows up, after entering credentials and when user clicks login button save a string preference value like this.

```
        with(
            requireContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "preference_login_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE
            ).edit()
        ) {
            putString(
                "preference_login_status",
                "user_logged_in"
            )
            commit()
        }
```

Now at this point we save preference string value as `user_logged_in` inside `preference_login_status` with key `preference_login_key` and going to next fragment.

At any point if user logs out from the app you have to change the value as `user_not_available` inside `preference_login_status` with key `preference_login_key` shown below.

```
        with(
            requireContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "preference_login_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE
            ).edit()
        ) {
            putString(
                "preference_login_status",
                "user_not_available"
            )
            commit()
        }
```

If you want to check whether there is an existing user from preferences, you can do this way and then decide at which point or destination the user has to be navigated to.

```
        val sharedPref = requireContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "preference_login_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )

        with(
            sharedPref.getString(
                "preference_login_status",
                "user_not_available"
            )
        ) {
            if (!this.equals("user_logged_in")) {
                // User is not logged-in, so take him back to login fragment
            }
        }
```

In above code, first get the preference we are referring(`preference_login_key`) to and read the string(`preference_login_status`) stored inside it. Now check or compare the both strings(`user_logged_in` and `user_not_available`). If the strings don't match, there is no user logged in, take the user back to the login screen.

Perform this check operations in `onCreate()` of the fragment.